# How to create a button group with css bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a button group with [css bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) framework.

I was able to create button-group with no problem. But, one of my buttons should be wrapped with a form to perform post request when clicking it.

Here is my code

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs pull-right" role="group">

    <a href="/salecategories" class="btn btn-primary" title="Show all salecategories">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>

    <a href="/salecategories/2/edit" class="btn btn-primary" title="Edit SaleCategory">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>

    <form method="POST" action="/salecategories/salecategory/2" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display: inline;" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input name="_method" value="DELETE" type="hidden">
    <input name="_token" value="8123RX6LbCpxo7LDdp3eettEXGzdfbS9gvzjbbWP" type="hidden">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Delete SaleCategory" onclick="return confirm(&quot;Confirm delete?&quot;)" id="sometest">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" title="Delete SaleCategory"></span>
        </button>
    </form>

</div>
```

The above code work but the "red button" is not aligned with the rest at the following screenshot shows.

How can I align the "red" button with the other two?

Here is a [jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30884/) to allow you to tinker with the code. Note, the fiddler shows the button now connected but the screenshot shows not aligned because I am using a different font for my app.

Comment: Why did you separate the last button from the other two? Could you not wrap all the buttons in the form?

Comment: I am not following you. only one button is wrapped in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the whole button group in the form. That way you can keep the three buttons together side by side.

```
<form action="/salecategories/salecategory/2">

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group">
        <a href="/salecategories" class="btn btn-primary">Show all</a>
        <a href="/salecategories/2/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to make the delete button the same size as the others?

Comment: Ok, I see what you are doing. It kinds fixed it. Please have a look at this updated fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30886/  the first button is not showing with round corners other than that it looks good. how can I fix the round corner?

Comment: @Jaylen The Reason why the first button is not rounded is because you have also inserted some hidden input elements into the `btn-group`. The `btn-group` should only contain visible elements of the class `btn`. Instead you could place the hidden elements at the end of the form (outside the group). [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30887/)